# What does it mean when A's column vectors are the solutions to Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_i$ are n-dimensional vectors. and $A\alpha_i = 0$ for every $\alpha_i$.
What are some properties of A? A feels kind of special.

Any thoughts? The row space and col space of A are perpendicular.

Maybe means $A^2$ is zero.
But what's the property here.

Comment: $A$'s columns being solutions to $Ax=0$ means exactly that $A^2=0$. What "$A$'s columns are **the** solutions to $Ax=0$" means is more cryptic, because $Ax=0$ has either one solution or infinitely many.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: You could also say that the image is contained in the nullspace. By the way, are we talking about a vector space over $ \mathbb R $? If it were over a finite field and $ A $'s columns were indeed precisely *the* solutions to $ Ax = 0$, that would be more interesting.